# Start container with multiple interfaces, one that routes to another docker image and another that uses bridge

Tags: docker, networking, interface

I'm trying to connect a docker image to another docker image while still retaining internet connection.

However, when I run

```
 docker run --net=bridge --net=ethereum-net -d -p 8080:8080 fe3a31e5d94d
```

I get

```
docker: conflicting options: cannot attach both user-defined and non-user-defined network-modes.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, docker networks will utilize a `bridge` network driver when being created.

In that case `--net=bridge` is not required when you run the containers.

Assuming `Ethereum-net` was created as a default bridge network, using `--net=ethereum-net` when running both containers will ensure both containers can communicate together, and they should still have external internet access. You can inspect the docker network to check the driver used to be sure.

If the containers on the network cannot communicate externally and the network is a bridge network, then you should inspect the subnet used for the bridge network to verify it does not overlap with your external network subnet. If there's an overlap, it won't route traffic correctly.